# Function ($ConvertPDFToGhostScriptDotNet) Error: Could not load file or assembly 'gsdll32.dll'

Tags: azure-functions

I have received these errors about every two days. When they show the function does not work:

Function ($ConvertPDFToGhostScriptDotNet) Error: Could not load file or assembly 'gsdll32.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

In the past I deleted the function and recreated. This morning I deleted it, recreated it, and I still got the error. Then an hour later it started working again.

The thing that makes this special is that I am manually adding the GhostScript (non .Net .dll) to the Nuget folder for GhostScript.Net (a /Net wrapper for GhostScript) using KUDU.

I documented my situation more fully here:
https://twitter.com/crandycodes/status/837711854285676544

Comment: Can you share more information about how you're referencing the library, and a small repro so we can take a closer look? If you can share this on a GH repo, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I put the files here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kq1lyrcsmzn6lj2/PDFtoPNG.zip?dl=0 To see how I copy the GhostScript dll to the Nuget directory for GhostScriptSharp manually see: https://twitter.com/ADefWebserver/status/837703651648917505

Comment: I made a blog post on what I did here: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/3303/Convert-PDF-files-to-PNG-Images-using-Azure-Functions.aspx

Comment: Michael, I'll be taking a look at this ASAP. Do you have a small repro that isolates the issue? Can you also confirm that restarting the site had no effect on this issue?

Comment: Have also been taking a look at some of your logs from this timeframe and most of the errors I'm seeing are unrelated to this particular problem. The one instance I see of this issue does seem to be indeed caused by missing DLLs. There's a package restore and some file changes a few successful executions (followed to additional iterations on the code). Did you happen to accidentally deploy the lock file with the function? Also, it would likely be easier to manage and safter if you deployed this native DLL with your files rather than placing it in the nuget cache.

Comment: I'll attempt to repro your issue, but if you do have an isolated repro, that would be helpful.

Comment: @FabioCavalcante - Your analysis of the logs seems correct. Yes I did accidently deploy the lock file (this was done out of ignorance). The gsdll32.dll is required by the NuGet package that is a managed code wrapper around gsdll32.dll. I was unable to put it in a place that allowed it to be found other than the Nuget cache. Also note that I cannot reproduce the error anymore. It was only happening the day that I reported it. Thank You.

Comment: @MichaelWashington Do you know what you did to get the error to stop happening? I'm running into the same issue you're describing here, after  following the GhostScript setup steps on your blog post.

Comment: @BobbyA - I did nothing. The error just went away. I know, not what you want to hear :(

Comment: For anyone dealing with this in the future, the problem just went away for me as well. Specifically, I deleted my project.json file (and associated lock file), and deleted the GhostScript.Net folder in data/Functions/packages/nuget. I verified the function was running, and then added all that back in, per the instructions in Michael's blog post. The error was no longer occurring, even though the configuration was exactly the same. If you're working with Azure support on this issue, here's my case number that they can reference: REG:118050418126619

Comment: I also ran into an issue where the function stopped triggering. Disabling the function, and then enabling it again, seems to resolve that problem for me.